# Seeking advice for receiving messages from multiple clients to single server

Tags: java, queue, netty

I am developing a client-server application using Netty v4.1.90.Final. I am still very new to the framework and relatively new to Java and programming.

The client side consists of a mock news feed which produces a POJO containing an int and a string. The mock news feed connects to the server with a keep alive TCP connection, and sends the POJO periodically. The client will send an initiating object in order to receive a "200" status code response from the server, after which it will begin sending objects for the server to consume.

The server side consists of a news analyser, which will accept the POJO and analyse the string and int for an arbitrary set of conditions. The server receives the initiating object, discards it, and responds with a "200" status code. When an object is received, it is placed in a queue (in this case a `LinkedBlockingQueue`. A news item analyser object then pops the next object in the queue to analyse it.

***NOTE:*** I am running both the client(s) and server on the same machine and connecting to the localhost on port 9001.

#### Expected Result:

When I run 2 or more instances of the client, I expect that the incoming messages will be received by Netty and passed to my decoder and `NewsAnalyserHandler` (see below) in an asynchronous fashion. When they reach the `NewsAnalyserHandler`, I expect that the decoded messages will be appended to the message queue in the order that they were received by Netty and the queue size will increase proportionally. I expect that not object will be overwritten as it is appended to the queue.

#### Actual Result:

When the decoded messages reach the `NewsAnalyserHandler`, they seem to overwrite eachother, depending on the order in which they were received. So if I receive 20 messages from 3 clients, I will end up with 20 messages in my queue, rather than the 3x20 messages I expect.

This overwriting behaviour can be seen in the log for the [News Analyser log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FICzq.png).

##### `NewsAnalyserHandler`

```java
public class NewsAnalyserHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewsAnalyserHandler.class);
    private static final String OK_TO_SEND = "200";
    private static final String STOP_SENDING = "507";

    private final BlockingQueue<NewsItem> messageQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        NewsItem request = (GeneratedNewsItem) msg;

        // If the NewsItem is the initiating object.
        if (request.getHeadline().equals("INIT") && request.getPriorty() == -1) {
            ctx.write(OK_TO_SEND);
            return;
        }

        // If the NewsItem can be inserted into the queue
        if (messageQueue.offer(request)) {
            logger.info("Received news item: {}", request);
            logger.info("Sending 200 response");
            ctx.write(OK_TO_SEND);
        }

        logger.info("Number of messages: {}", messageQueue.size());
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);

    }

    //...

}
```

The 2 decoders which I used:

##### `NewsItemByteDecoder`

```java
public class NewsItemByteDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        while (in.isReadable()) {
            int strLen = in.readInt();
            byte[] headlineBytes = new byte[strLen];
            in.readBytes(headlineBytes);
            String headline = new String(headlineBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int priority = in.readInt();
            NewsItem ni = GeneratedNewsItem.createNewsItem(priority, headline);
            ctx.fireChannelRead(ni);
        }
    }

}
```

##### `NewsItemDecoder`

```java
public class NewsItemDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<NewsItem> {

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        int strLen = in.readInt();
        byte[] headlineBytes = new byte[strLen];
        in.readBytes(headlineBytes);
        String headline = new String(headlineBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int priority = in.readInt();
        NewsItem ni = GeneratedNewsItem.createNewsItem(priority, headline);
        out.add(ni);
    }
    
}
```

My bootstrapping is as follows:

##### `NewsAnalyser` bootstrapping class

```java
public final class NewsAnalyser {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 9001;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewsAnalyser.class);

    private int port;

    public NewsAnalyser(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : DEFAULT_PORT;

        new NewsAnalyser(port).run();

    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new NewsItemByteDecoder())
                                         .addLast(new ServerResponseEncoder(),
                                                  new NewsAnalyserHandler());
                        }

                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture future = b.bind(port).sync();
            logger.info("Starting News Analyser on localhost:{}", port);
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            logger.info("Shutting down News Analyser on localhost:{}", port);
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using both the `ReplayingDecoder<T>` and the `ByteToMessageDecoder`, with the exact same effect.

I have also tried using a number of differing data structures for the  including `List`, `BlockingQueue` and `concurrentLinkedQueue`. I have also tried adding the `synchronized` keyword to the `channelRead()` method and I have tried executing the method body with a `ReentrantLock`, but to no avail.
All this effort tells me that I am not fundamentally understanding a concept for how the TCP traffic is received and processed by Netty. Or just as likely, I am not understanding a concept in Java for queues or synchronizing.

Any advice for getting this application working as expected or even pointers to possibly similar posts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anythignabout netty, but I expect that several instances of `NewsAnalyserHandler` are being created.

Comment: @tgdavies you were exactly right, thank you so much for that pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Turns outs I didn't understand that Netty creates a `NewsAnalyserHandler` for each client that sending messages to the server.

This can be seen in [this log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64C0v.png). I ran 2 instances of the client and for each instance ran, Netty appears to create a `NewsAnalyserHandler`.

My solution was to declare a `LinkedBlockingQueue` in the `NewsAnalyser` class and pass that object as a constructor argument for the `NewsAnalyserHandler`.

I have posted the modified code below.

```java
public final class NewsAnalyser {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 9001;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewsAnalyser.class);

    // Newly declared `LinkedBlockingQueue`
    private static final BlockingQueue<NewsItem> newsItemQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private int port;

    public NewsAnalyser(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : DEFAULT_PORT;

        new NewsAnalyser(port).run();

    }

    public void run() throws InterruptedException {

        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new NewsItemByteDecoder()).addLast(new ServerResponseEncoder(),
                                    // Passing the `LinkedBlockingQueue` in as a constructor.
                                    new NewsAnalyserHandler(newsItemQueue));
                        }

                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        // start server
          
        } finally {
            // shutdown server
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class NewsAnalyserHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewsAnalyserHandler.class);
    private static final String OK_TO_SEND = "200";
    private static final String STOP_SENDING = "507";

    // Declare local `BlockingQueue<T>`
    private BlockingQueue<NewsItem> newsItemQueue;

    // Assign passed in `LinkedBlockingQueue`
    public NewsAnalyserHandler(BlockingQueue<NewsItem> newsItemQueue) {
        this.newsItemQueue = newsItemQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

        NewsItem request = (GeneratedNewsItem) msg;

        if (request.getHeadline().equals("INIT") && request.getPriorty() == -1) {
            ctx.write(OK_TO_SEND);
            return;
        }

        if (newsItemQueue.offer(request)) {
            logger.info("Received news item: {}", request);
            logger.info("Sending 200 response");
            ctx.write(OK_TO_SEND);
        }

        logger.info("Number of messages: {}", newsItemQueue.size());
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);

    }
    
    // Channel read complete & exception handling

}
```

After I made the modifications to the code, [this log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3rI.png) shows that the `NewsAnalyserHandler` now functions as expected.